# Standard Method for setting Log Level in MISRA C

Tags: c, logging

**BACKGROUND:** In C++, the standard way to set the log level (DEBUG, WARN, ERR, etc) for a singleton logging class is via an environment variable. That way, the programmer doesn't have to pass the log level around. Also, any subprocess inherits the parent's log level by default. The downside is that walking the environment table is O(n), so you don't want to check it every time you log a message. Instead, it is checked once at start-up and never again. However, this is considered acceptable because the log level is not expected to change over the lifetime of the process.

**QUESTION:** What is the standard way to set the log level in MISRA-compliant C (or just C in general)? Is there a universally accepted approach to this or does everyone just decide for themselves? **To be clear: I am asking about the generally accepted way to implement this for a custom logging library, not syslog. I am not asking for language-specific support, just if there is a standard way to achieve this functionality.**

**REASON FOR ASKING:** I am new to MISRA C and am working with an existing code base in which each process takes the log level as a command-line parameter and passes it to the singleton logger in main(). I want to know if this design is common and accepted or just a quirk of whoever designed it.

Comment: What you are asking about seems to be some application-specific de facto way of doing things. MISRA-C isn't really concerned about "the application layer" of your code. So I don't see how the design you describe would conflict with MISRA-C. That being said, it is perfectly possible to create a singleton class with inheritance in C, by using opaque types and a `static` file scope variable. Opaque types are even encouraged by MISRA-C:2012 Dir 4.8.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like a language feature, but rather a run-time environment one.

If you have any POSIX compatibility layer, then you'd get more details about `syslog(3)` documentation and its related `<syslog.h>`.
This is POSIX, though, so it's C more than C++.

Anyway, level for a single logging message is selected at the emission time with the call  `syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...)` where the 1st argument is the priority, which is finally the message level.

The easiest way is to simply call `openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility)` at the program startup and then to call the `syslog()` anytime you need it. You'd then filter from the system logs.

As an option you can setup a "*log filter*", a int value to be checked against each time a new log is emitted. You skip to call the `syslog()` if the level doesn't qualify.